# Oracle: How to determine if a column is a "boolean"?

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean

I create quasi-boolean columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
    bar NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL CHECK (hide IN (0, 1))
```

I'm currently scraping `user_tab_columns` and would like to be able to determine whether a given column is a boolean or not.  So far, I've got this:

```
SELECT column_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   all_constraints
        WHERE  table_name = table_name
        AND    constraint_type = 'C'
        AND    REGEXP_LIKE(search_condition, '^ *' || column_name || ' +IN *\( *0, *1 *\) *$', 'i')) is_boolean
FROM   user_tab_columns;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 31
```

I've learned that this is because the `search_condition` data type is `LONG`, and `REGEXP_LIKE()` expects a character type, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Am I going about this the right way?  If so, how do I fix the error I'm getting?  If not, what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: I apologize, Stack Overflow is giving me errors on post submission and edits.  This was a real question, I swear :(

Comment: It seems to not like the parentheses `(` `)` that were wrapped around my `CREATE TABLE` query... ????

Comment: Personally I prefer a CHAR(1) constrained as NOT NULL CHECK(colname IN ('Y', 'N')).  IMO numbers are prone to misuse in ways that CHAR fields are not.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Oracle comments :

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN foo.bar is 'Boolean';
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the LONG datatype is very difficult to work with.  One way round this is to create a function to return the search condition of a constraint as a varchar2:

```
create or replace
function search_condition
( p_owner varchar2
, p_constraint_name varchar2
) return varchar2
is
  l_text long;
begin
  select search_condition into l_text from all_constraints
  where owner = p_owner
  and constraint_name = p_constraint_name;
  return l_text;
end;
```

Now you can use this in your query:

```
select constraint_name, search_condition from
(
select constraint_name, search_condition (owner, constraint_name) search_condition
from all_constraints
where constraint_type = 'C'
and owner = 'TONYEOR'
)
where  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you application, but it may be sufficient to look at the column type, scale, and precision. I don't think I've ever seen a `number(1)` used for anything but a Boolean in an Oracle database.

Comment: I have the case ;) (and I'm absolutely ok on the fact that it's an horrible choice). But your answer seems to be currently valid. For example, Devart connector for .Net transforms all number(1) in boolean

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a safe assumption for my particular application, as we have several `NUMBER(1)` columns with non-boolean data.